# How to protect my software that runs offline? (Expired license - Java)

Tags: java

I am Developing software for a client and I'm almost done. However, not yet chosen the method to validate my software, protecting it from piracy. My offline software runs, how to make my client can not hack my software (or Nearly so)? I've thought about validating the date of the clock, the MAC, serial HD, but does not seem very safe.
I appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: there is no way you can completely secure this.
You can obfuscate your code and make it harder to be cracked, but it just makes it harder, not impossible.

Comment: The client is running *your* software on *his* computer.  That means while he may not be able to manipulate your code, he can certainly change every aspect about his computer (yes, even MAC, serial HD, etc. if he installs it on a virtual machine).  There is only one sure way to validate the software and that is by an external source, and even then, you should exchange codes that change on a daily basis from client to server.  If you just return "OK", then that can be emulated so the software will be tricked into thinking that server validated.

Comment: The only way to protect your application is to not allow them to download your software, even then they can create software which does exactly the same thing from using it.  You should focus on how to make it harder.

Comment: Don't go overboard. Of course it is valid, to spent some energy here; but seriously: if people are willing to buy your software; chances are that they will not start cheating on you later on. Example: JetBrains is extremely successful with their IDEs; and one core point is: they just deliver cool technology to their customers. People don't cheat; because the product is so good that they are more than willing to pay for it.